# Compiling RtMidi - Qt Project, mingw

Tags: c++, qt, midi

I´ve been trying to compile RtMidi (http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/) in a Windows environment (QtCreator, mingw) for hours now. Reading other threads has not been helpful.

As recommended in another post I added the following lines to my .pro-file in order to compile the Microsoft Multimedia API.

```
DEFINES += __WINDOWS_MM__
LIBS += -lwinmm
```

`RtMidi::getCompiledApi()` returns the non-functional RtMidi Dummy API only.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was solved by placing the `DEFINES += __WINDOWS_MM__` definition into RtMidi.h instead of the .pro-file.

I´ve seen the line placed in the .pro-file of an open source project and copied from there, can´t tell whether or why it worked for them.